# Heads of state convicted in international court

Tags: contemporary-history

From [this BBC News article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-21134892):

> Taylor became the first former head of state to be convicted of war crimes by an international court since the Nuremberg trials of Nazis after World War II.

What former head of state was convicted of war crimes at the Nuremberg trials, if any?

Comment: This looks like a factual error on behalf of BBC (see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_trials#Intelligence_tests_and_psychiatric_assessments) for a list of accused, ordered by descending IQs). BTW, the heading of your question does not quite match its body (only the latter asks specifically about Nuremberg).

Comment: @gerrit - it could be merely an English hprasing problem... they were not necessarily implying that any heads of state WERE convicted at that time

Comment: @DVK ... then they could equally well have written "since the birth of Napoleon"... I think it *does* imply someone was convicted in Nuremberg.

Comment: @gerrit - possible. English can be imprecise :(  We should all switch to C

Comment: @gerrit not really. It just means that they didn't look at data from before the Nuremberg trials. As to nobody being convicted at an international court, such things didn't technically exist until the Nuremberg trials (and those were more like military tribunals than civil courts). As to heads of state being "convicted" earlier, I'd guess the killing of Mayan and Aztec kings for heresy by the conquistadores in the 1500s would count, but of course there was no real court in session, just a priest and a general declaring sentence and calling in the executioner afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, [Donitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_D%C3%B6nitz) as head of the [Flensburg Government](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flensburg_Government).